# Firebird local vs remote connection

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have a cloud-service based on firebird databases. Every customer has his own database file. So many connection-definitions are loaded into my service at startup. This works all well.

Currently the load for the server is ok so the database files are on the same machine as the service itself. Later I could extend it by another server.

My question is:
Does it matter if I use a local firebird connection or should I prefer a remote connection (via TCP/IP). Although I am on the same machine. 
Are there advantages / disadvantages or any limits? I got a lot of requests to this server.

I am using Firebird 2.5.7 (64Bit).

Comment: on Windows local (XNET) connection should work slightly faster, than TCP/IP localhost connection. On UNIX there should be little difference.